# My Django server is not responding anything

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web

Basically when I enter this command :- 
$- python manage.py runserver 
In command prompt it's shows my server address which is usually http://127.0.0.1:8000/
But when I enter this in Chrome it's doesn't showing me anything just showing "This site can't be reached"
Please help me out because I am new to Django.. 
I also typed the command like
$- python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0.8000
And this 
$- python manage.py runserver [::] :8000
But still I can't see Django "Rocket".. !!
And also I thing I want to tell that I am using WiFi for internet . So it's OK or else using Django server we need lan connection.

Comment: Is your browser on the same machine as the one you are running your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the steps in this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) you will be able to get your first app started.

Make sure you are in the directory where `manage.py` is located before you run `python manage.py runserver`

Django can be used with WiFi without any problems.